# How can I resent the order confirmation email?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd, order-email, confirmation

Due to other extension conflicts some of my order confirmation emails weren't send. How can I sent them manually via backend?

Comment: on order detail page there is button to send email to customer just click on that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send them email from back-end via navigate to **sales->orders**

then click on any order which you want to send mail and click on **'Send Email'** button top right above the order details.

[image: See the image for send Email button]